# how i display Items beside each others on content place holders?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I want to retrieve items from the database and display its on row inside the row three columns inside every column one card, the card have on item.

this is my masterpage:

```html
<div class="products bg-dark">
        <div class="container pt-3 pb-3">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            </div>
```

and here is my index.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="Index" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
         <div class="row" >
             <div id="s" class='col-md-4 pt-3' runat="server">

                 </div>
             </div>
</asp:Content>
```

and here is my index.aspx.cs:

```
 con.Open();

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select ID , title , sub_title , image from Articles", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

      while (dr.Read())
        {
            s.InnerHtml +=   
                "<div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' src=images/" + dr["image"] + " alt='Card image cap'>" +
                "<div class='card-body'>" +
                "<h5 class='card-title'>" + dr["title"] + "</h5>" +
                "<p class='card-text'>" + dr["sub_title"] + "</p><a href = 'Article.aspx?x=" + dr["ID"] + "class='btn btn-primary'>Read more</a></div>" +
                " </div>" +
                "</div>"
```

The problem is when I run the code. The cards don't display beside each other. its display under each other,
and when inspect I found only the first item inside the content place holders, the second item not inside.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the class of the columns (class='col-md-4 pt-3') to each card.
Therefore, pass the class to the div inside the dynamic html.

Comment: its still under each others i want become beside each others

Answer (score 0):

try removing class='col-md-4' from div with id="s" (in index.aspx page) and place this class for div of each card (in index.aspx.cs page)

Comment: i am trying that its still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to add style="display: block;" to the outer div (with the id="s").
and style="display:inline-block;" to each of the cards.